# Does puppeteer support PUT method

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Like the title.
Im trying to automatically crawling data and then edit them using puppeteer, heres my code

```
page2.on('request', interceptedRequest => {
            var data = {
                'method': 'PUT',
                'putData':  JSON.stringify(stage),
                'headers': {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };
            interceptedRequest.continue(data);
});
```

So i encounter an error as the response from the server

```
{"timestamp":"2021-01-23T14:19:01.276+00:00","status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported"}
```

Any ideas guys? Thanks for reading

```
Edit: i have also tried postData in the intercept
```

Comment: I don't see a reason why not, have you tried to use a different tool like Postman to see if the server handles PUT requests correctly?

Comment: Puppeteer doesnt support Put for intercept, i was being stupid at that time, i can just simply call ajax/fetch to the server but because of mindset at that time of mine was just using puppeteer to do everything